# how to get the result of exec statement via LINQ

Tags: sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

i have select statement created problematically in sql-server-2008 procedure

and i have it executed like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DoSomething
AS
BEGIN
declare @command nvarchar(500);
set @command = N'select * from sometable';
exec @command;
END
```

of course the select statement is not this simple
I add this procedure to linq class and got this message:
[image]
 - if i can't use this method to call this procedure what can i do
 - or is there anything i can do else

Edit:

I even tried to run this procedure via ado.net but i got exception:
SqlException procedure select * from sometable does not exist

any alternate way please

Comment: I never got in to using lINQ but I thought the whole point of it was to not have to use dynamic SQL? Can't you query the "objects" created by LINQ?

Comment: it's a little complicated i can't

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message it seems your stored proc is returning multiple result sets or you are using a temp table

Have a look at these Posts

[Post 1](http://riteshkk2000.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/error-unknown-return-type-return-types.html)

[Post 2](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/45/posts/12025/how-to-get-multiple-result-set-of-procedure-using-linq-to-sql.aspx)